# Wordpress editor weird scripts

Tags: wordpress

I've just noticed that when I switch from Visual to the Text view in WordPress I get some script tags inserted. Their URLs are https://promappdev.com/ and https://loadsource.org/ with some values set.

I didn't installed any new plugins lately so not sure what could be creating this scripts on my website. Anyone else having a similar problem? Ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Fixed: there was chrome extension problem. I removed it and now there are no scripts added.

Comment: Do you know which extension you had installed? I tried to debug this (I don't use wordpress) by removing the new extensions, but still lots of data are pushed to promappdev.com. They also load https://s3.amazonaws.com/js-cache/1d073454a5f6e5bf7b.js, which initiates this.

Comment: I had some POSTMAN extension, not sure how it got installed since it's deprecated and POSTMAN is now used as an app.

Comment: Great, I too have that. I had explicitly installed the postman app. I will try removing it and test. In the last 30 mins, I find that this 1do73...7b.js (hosted on amazonaws) is very scary -- it's modifying the search results, posting all browsing data to promappdev.com and not sure if it's taking passwords/card details.

Comment: Missed out mentioning, but yes, removing the postmal extension helped getting rid of all the above issues. Honestly, I didn't suspect postman initially, as the app was a very good tool. Thanks for your pointer!